# kafka consumer message polling issue

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I am using kafka in processing some messages, but issue I am facing is that consumer is not polling the max records available to it. Let's say my max poll records are 500, but consumer is only consuming 25-35 records on average.

How can I maximize the number of poll records?

```
channel_consumer.consume_many_offsets(
            execute_threshold_handler_task,
            error_callback,
            max_records=config.get("max_poll_records"),
            timeout_ms=config.get("max_poll_interval_ms"),
        )
```

I am trying to use the consumer at it's full potential by consuming max messages

Comment: Check whether 500 messages is available on the broker, then check if you face `max.partition.fetch.bytes` and `fetch.max.bytes` limtations

Comment: What library is this?

Comment: @gdomo, I tweaked some settings and then consumer was able to fetch 500 messages in which one message was of 6.7KB, thus it fetched 3.5 MB data.

but when my one message is of 42KB then and other configurations are:
max_poll_records: 1500
fetch_max_bytes: 100MB
max_partition_fetch_bytes: 150 MB
it is polling only 57MB of data which is around 1365 messages.

any suggestion how can I maximize it to poll 1500 messages.

Comment: @OneCricketeer it is KafkaLibrary
I've written a wrapper on it to tweaks the parameters.